# Can $S^4$ be the cotangent bundle of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-topology

I am asking the question because in the classical mechanics book by Arnold, he states that there is a **distinguished** 1-form on $T^*V $. It seems that there is no such distinguished 1-form on a general even-dimensional manifold.

So, not every even-dimensional manifold can be the phase space of a system, or not every even-dimensional manifold can be a cotangent bundle?

Is $S^2$ a cotangent bundle (intuitively it is not)? How about $S^4$?

Comment: That's a pure math question.

Comment: Ups: Noticed crossposting: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1402849/11127 Please don't crosspost. Instead ask for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the total space of a cotangent bundle $T^*M$ is always non-compact, while a sphere $S^{2n}$ is compact.