# Examples of "common" smooth manifolds arrising as vector bundles

Tags: soft-question, smooth-manifolds

Can $S^n$ be realized as a vector bundle of some smooth manifold? What about a Torus? Klein Bottle?

My professor introduced us to fiber bundles today. Am I correct in understanding that we could realize an orientable surface of genus 1 as a a fiber bundle over $S^1$ where each fiber is diffeomorphic to $S^1$?

General insights an examples appreciated.. Thanks MSE!!

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1402849/39599). In particular, my answer there shows that the answer is no for all of the proposed manifolds.

Comment: Well, if you allow rank 0 vector bundles then sure. Otherwise, see Michael Albanese's answer.

Comment: Is this about fibre bundles or vector bundles?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Not the first time this week I had to be reminded about those. I have edited my answer.